# Estimating the Similarity between Two Unpaired Datasets

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to compare the data (black) and the model (color). [Fig. 1]

[image: Model (color) and data (black)]

There is another example [Fig. 2]. The data set and the model are different for Fig. 1 and  Fig. 2.
[image: Model (color) and data (black)]

In both the cases, it appears that there are overlaps between the model and data, however, the overlap/matching is better for Fig. 2. I would like   to quantify the correlation of the data and the model for both the cases in order to distinguish  between the "goodness of fit" of both the figures. I was wondering which (statistical) method I should use to estimate the correlation quantitatively.

Comment: What is your language? R or Python?

Comment: @Pascal I'm using Python.

Comment: So why the "r" tag? Removed.

Comment: What is the meaning of the plots, though. For each black dot, there is a specific corresponding color dot?

Comment: @AmiTavory No, there is no one-to-one relation between the data and the model.  For each of the figures, the data represents the values of x and y for different conditions. I tried to model the various possibilities and represent my results with colored points. Now I'm trying to see if the model points [color] are good enough to represent the data [black].

Comment: @rana can you elaborate what the plots show? what is modeled to what? and please don't say that the black points are modeled to the colored ones

Comment: @ZachiShtain I tried to explain the plot in my above comment. To be more precise, my data is a 2d array (x,y) of length m and my model is a 2d array (x,y) of length n. I'm interested to quantify the "overlap" between the data and the model as shown in the scatter plot.

Comment: @rana, it seems you are trying to compare between two datasets. Have you considered using the center of gravity and the disparity matrices for the comparison?

Comment: @ZachiShtain it will be helpful if you kindly explain the methods. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could start by calculating the center of gravity for each dataset using `numpy.mean` and compare how close their are to one another.
Next step is to check the if each center is inside the uncertainty ellipse (http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/) of the other dataset.

Finally, I would recommend to using hypotheses testing like student's test or f-test. There are some methods in `scipy` for these kind of test, just look at the documentation